# Can someone suggest a good strategy for waitlists for memberships'?

Tags: drupal, civimember

Right off the bat I can think of an easy way to get on a waitlist by creating a membership sign-up contribution page where the only payment method is "pay later" and automatically adding waitlist group to the user.

But transitioning from waitlist to active and paying dues????  And maybe self-service viewing of where a waitlist member is on the list (sort waitlist group by date and counting the row number?)???

Ideas?

Comment: I edited your question because waitlist functionality would normally refer to events.

Comment: can  you clarify what you mean by 'waitlisting' a membership - do you mean eg it is pending a committee approval?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion , this is a private club with a cap on membership.  jon-g-megaphone-tech yes, waiting list would normally be more for events in general and I may need that too but this particular case is for membership.  By the way, I saw an old 2009 post that mentioned they were putting WL into core events.  Do you know if that ever happened?

Comment: WL is already in Events. perhaps I mis-understood you?

Comment: I might end up using WL on events but for now the immediate need is WL for membership.  Too many member requests and not enough resources to serve the members so we need to stop accepting new members until some resign.